# Multiple `case let` clauses in swift

Tags: json, serialization, switch-statement, swift3

Here is the code (mostly copied from http://codelle.com/blog/2016/5/an-easy-way-to-convert-swift-structs-to-json/):

```
import Foundation

protocol JsonRepresentable {
    var JsonRepresentation: AnyObject {get}
}

protocol JsonSerializable: JsonRepresentable {
}

extension JsonSerializable {
    var JsonRepresentation: AnyObject {
        var representation = [String: AnyObject]()
        for case let (label?, value) in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
            switch value {
            case let value as JsonRepresentable:
                representation[label] = value.JsonRepresentation
            case let value as NSNumber:
                representation[label] = value
            case let value as NSString:
                representation[label] = value
            case let value as NSArray:
                representation[label] = value
            case let value as NSDictionary:
                representation[label] = value
            case let value as NSNull:
                representation[label] = value
            default:
                break

            }
        }
        return representation as AnyObject
    }

    func toJson() -> String? {
        let representation = JsonRepresentation
        guard JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(representation) else {
            return nil
        }
        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: representation, options: [])
            return String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct Owner: JsonSerializable {
    var name: String
}

struct Car: JsonSerializable {
    var manufacturer: String
    var model: String
    var mileage: Float
    var owner: Owner
}

let car = Car(manufacturer: "Kia", model: "K23", mileage: 143.3, owner: Owner(name: "娴静"))
print(car.toJson())
```

Everything works as expected, the only problem I have is that the branches of `NSString, NSNumber, NSArray` etc are exactly the same. How can I avoid this redundancy?

Comment: Call me crazy but I see every possible branch is the same except for the default, not just `NSString`, `NSNumber`, and `NSArray`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `case let` you can use `is` which is cascadable

```
extension JsonSerializable {
    var JsonRepresentation: Any {
        var representation = [String: Any]()
        for case let (label?, value) in Mirror(reflecting: self).children {
            switch value {
            case let value as JsonRepresentable:
                representation[label] = value.JsonRepresentation
            case is NSNumber, is NSString, is NSArray, is NSDictionary, is NSNull: representation[label] = value
            default:
                break

            }
        }
        return representation as Any
    }

 ....
```

Consider that JSON is `Any` in Swift 3

Comment: Why is `AnyObject` not appropriate here? The IDE doesn't complain about this, strange.

Comment: This this case you can even use `AnyObject` unless you want to replace the `NS...` types with the Swift native structs.

Comment: It seems the doc of `JSONSerialization ` explicitly requires NS... types. Anyways, it's probably outdated.

Comment: Just one more thing, what is the question mark in `let (label?...` for?

Comment: No, the first parameter of `data(withJSONObject` is `Any` which includes also the Swift native types. The question mark indicates that `label` is an optional.